# Bootstrap React hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

EDIT:

I'm trying react-bootstrap, since it supports tooltips as well! But I still cannot get the desired tooltip effect. The button shows up with the correct styling, but there is no tooltip effect when mousing over the button.

my code:

```
import { Tooltip, OverlayTrigger, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

    const tooltip = (
      <Tooltip id="tooltip"><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.</Tooltip>
    );


    export default function Test (props) {
        return (
            <OverlayTrigger placement="right" overlay={tooltip}>
                <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
            </OverlayTrigger>
        )
```

Comment: Why don't you give [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tooltips) a try? It's more react way than using just bootstrap.

Comment: Are you importing the boostrap style AND js file in your `index.html`?

Comment: WIth react-bootstrap, all you do is import the npm module, no CDN or scripts

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the overlay triggers by hovering the element.

Like this:

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="hover" placement="right" overlay={tooltip}>
    <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

You can find more information [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers-trigger-behaviors).

Comment: I tried that too, both trigger=hover and trigger=click, nothing makes the tooltip appear.

Comment: @JaimePericas It seems to be working. Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/1f2c56ya/1/). Also keep in mind that react-bootstrap supports bootstrap 3 and, in version 4, bootstrap made some class name changes that might lead to compatibility issues (happened to me with the Modal) so if you are using version 4 then you could use https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/